# Exam drop down menu is not appearing

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve exams(sessions) depending on the module the teacher has chosen from the previous drop down menu.

For Example:

**Module selected from drop down:** CHI2332 (ModuleId) Advanced Database Systems (ModuleName)

**Exam(Session) shown in drop down:**

AAA (SessionId) 24-04-2012 (SessionDate) 11:00:00 (Session Time)
ARF (SessionId) 13-06-2012 (SessionDate) 14:00:00 (Session Time)
EFT (SessionId) 10-09-2012 (SessionDate) 09:00:00 (Session Time)

It should display the exams above in the drop down menu as these exams match the moduleId chosen from the module dropdown menu and the TeacherId for these exams belong to the Teacher Username logged into to this page.

The problem is that in the Exam drop down menu, it cannot seem to find any exams even though the modules are legitimate for those exams and hence it should display those exams in the drop down menu.

It just outputs this error below in its place:

```
Sessions: Notice: Undefined variable: sessionHTML in /.../ on line 178
```

How can I get the exams to appear in the drop down menu when it should do?

Below are the database tables:

**Session Table:**

```
SessionId SessionDate SessionTime ModuleId  
AAA       24-04-2012  11:00:00    CHI2332 
ARF       13-06-2012  14:00:00    CHI2332 
EFT       10-09-2012  09:00:00    CHI2332
```

**Module Table:**

```
ModuleId  ModuleName
CHI2332   Advanced Database Systems
```

Below is the php/mysqli code:

```
<?php

         // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

   $courseid = (isset($_POST['courseid'])) ? $_POST['courseid'] : '';

   ?>

       <h1>DELETING AN ASSESSMENT</h1>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
         <p>Course ID: <input type="text" name="courseid" /><input id="courseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>      
        </form>


        <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $query = "
                 SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
                 c.CourseName,
                 m.ModuleName
                 FROM Course c
                 INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
                 JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
                 WHERE
                 (c.CourseId = ?)
                 ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId
                ";

    $qrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $qrystmt->bind_param("s",$courseid);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

    $qrystmt->execute(); 

    $qrystmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);

     $qrystmt->store_result();

    $num = $qrystmt->num_rows();

    if($num ==0){
        echo "<p>Sorry, No Course was found with this Course ID '$courseid'</p>";
    } else { 

        $dataArray = array();

 while ( $qrystmt->fetch() ) { 
          // data array
          $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['CourseName'] = $dbCourseName; 
          $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['Modules'][$dbModuleId]['ModuleName'] = $dbModuleName; 
           // session data
          $_SESSION['idcourse'] = $dbCourseId;
          $_SESSION['namecourse'] = $dbCourseName;

    }

     foreach ($dataArray as $courseId => $courseData) {

          $output = ""; 

          $output .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseId .  " - "  . $courseData['CourseName'] . "</p>";

       $moduleHTML = ""; 
       $moduleHTML .= '<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
       $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
            foreach ($courseData['Modules'] as $moduleId => $moduleData) {        

            $moduleHTML .= "<option value='$moduleId'>" . $moduleId . " - " . $moduleData['ModuleName'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
  } 
            }
            $moduleHTML .= '</select>';

      echo $output;

        }


        ?>

         <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
         <p>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="modulesubmit" /></p>      
        </form> 



        <?php

    }

 if (isset($_POST['modulesubmit'])) {

     var_dump($_POST['modulesDrop']);

            $sessionquery = "
                 SELECT SessionId, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
                 FROM Session
                 WHERE
                 (ModuleId = ?)
                 ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
                ";

    $sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modulesDrop']);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

    $sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

    $sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

     $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

    $sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

        $dataArraySession = array();

 while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) { 

     $dataArraySession[$dbModuleId]['Sessions'][$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSesisonDate['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime; 

    }

    foreach ($dataArraySession as $sessionId => $sessionData) {

       $sessionHTML = ""; 
       $sessionHTML .= '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
       $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           
       $sessionHTML .= "<option value='$sessionId'>" . $sessionId . " - " . $sessionData['SessionDate']. " - " . $sessionData['SessionTime'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
       $sessionHTML .= '</select>';
            }


     if ($sessionnum > 0) {

 ?>

         <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
         <p>Sessions: <?php echo $sessionHTML; ?><input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="sesionsubmit" /></p>      
        </form>       

<?php

    }

    else {
   echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Sessions under this Module</p>";
}


}


        ?>
```

Link to application is here: [Application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/deletesession.php)

Comment: Please show an example of the relevant HTML.  We need to know what True/False and Yes/No buttons look like (classes, element types, etc...).  We need to know where the input field that is created would go in the HTML relative to what was clicked.

Comment: Also, what is a "standard button" (as mentioned in your question) and how is it different from a Yes/No or True/False button?

Comment: What happens when value === "No" or "False" in the first two ternaries?

Comment: Line 178 is this line is the form `<p>Sessions: <?php echo $sessionHTML; ?><input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="sesionsubmit" /></p>`

Comment: Nowhere in the code you supplied is $sessionHTML defined. You are trying to echo an undefined variable. It is impossible to help you unless you post a link or more code

Comment: @davidstrachan I have included whole code and link to the application. To use application, type in "info101" in search bar for course and submit, then when the module drop down appears, select a module then submit, then it shows the problem of not displaying sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a typo here (line: 111):

`$dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['Sessions']['SessionDate'] = $dbSesisonDate['SessionTime'] = $dbSesisonTime;`

You binded parameter is called `$dbSessionTime` and you're assigning `$dbSesisonTime` to your `$dataArraySession` array. This would cause `$dataArraySession` not to filled up by any value in your while loop in line 109. Subsequently the `foreach` loop in line 115 will never be executed and because `$sessionHTML` is defined inside this loop, will be undefined later on when you use it in line 131

PS: The provided link for your application requires authentication to proceed.

**EDIT** to provide a code sample in case no data exist for a particular `courseId`:

Wrap lines `130-132` inside an `if` statement in order to be sure that the drop-down will be displayed only if some results are found

```
if ($sessionnum > 0) {
   // display your form
}
else {
   echo "No results found!";
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I said you need to be logged in my script to access the page.

Comment: Ok I changed the typo but still getting same problem, you was saying there is something wrong with the $sessionHTML, can you please provide me a sample of code on how you would display the foreach loop and $sessionHTML, I have to go to work but I will be back later on tonight and see your answer, if correct obviously you get points :)

Comment: Hi, I am now getting this error when I tried your edit `Notice: Undefined variable: sessionHTML in /...on line 166 ` This is pointing to this line: `$sessionHTML .= '</select>';` I updated the code above which matches your edit

Comment: Btw I updated the application link so tha now you are able to see what the application looks like

Comment: The `$sessionHTML .= '</select>';` line needs to be inside the `foreach loop`. Move it just before the closing curly bracket `}`

Comment: Hi, This has got rid of th error which is great. Only problem is that it keeps stating that it cannot find a session. It should be able to find a session from a module and display it in a drop down menu. Am I doing something wrong in my fetch() statement?

Comment: `$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$moduleId); ` this should hold the `moduleId` POSTed by your form, that would be `$_POST['modulesDrop'];` so change that to: `$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modulesDrop']); `

Comment: Hi, changed it but still can't find any sessions. Code updated

Comment: Comment out `$sessionqrystmt->store_result(); ` and try again

Comment: As it is getting long...try debug each section of your program to make sure that everything works as expected, you can use `var_dump` for this purpose, i.e `var_dump($_POST['modulesDrop']);`. If you verify that the value passed from the form is the one expected proceed to the following block of code (`foreach`) again using `var_dump` etc...

Comment: Ok by doing the `var_dump($_POST['modulesDrop'])` I actually am receving no value after submitting the module's drop down menu, I am receiving this error: `Notice: Undefined index: modulesDrop in /.../ on line 128 NULL` This is the line where the var_dump() has occurred. Any ideas on what I need to do to be able to retrieve the value?

Comment: Your form opening tag doesn't include the `select` for the course. Move the `<form>` opening tag just before entering the `foreach` loop. Final try as I have answered about 10 different questions in one shot!

Comment: I have included whole code in question and link to application. Can you have one more look at code and see what else is wrong? When you said move the `<from>` tag, which one do you mean? The form for course, module or session because I'm a little confused which one I should be moving?

Comment: To use application, type in "info101" in search bar for course and submit, then when the module drop down appears, select a module then submit, then it shows the problem of not displaying sessions

Comment: @user1723760 Ok...change the line `$dataArraySession[$dbModuleId]['Sessions'][$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSesisonDate['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime;` to these two lines: `$dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSessionDate; $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime;` inside `while ($sessionqrystmt->fetch())` on line: 128 of the posted code

Answer (score 0):

Change `$sessionHTML .= '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;`

To  `$sessionHTML .= '<select name="sessionsDrop" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;`

It is name not id that is passed in POST

```
<?php

     // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

 /* check connection */
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
die();
}

 $courseid = (isset($_POST['courseid'])) ? $_POST['courseid'] : '';

?>

   <h1>DELETING AN ASSESSMENT</h1>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Course ID: <input type="text" name="courseid" /><input id="courseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>      
    </form>


    <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $query = "
             SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
             c.CourseName,
             m.ModuleName
             FROM Course c
             INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
             JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
             WHERE
             (c.CourseId = ?)
             ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId
            ";

$qrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$qrystmt->bind_param("s",$courseid);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$qrystmt->execute(); 

$qrystmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);

 $qrystmt->store_result();

$num = $qrystmt->num_rows();

if($num ==0){
    echo "<p>Sorry, No Course was found with this Course ID '$courseid'</p>";
} else { 

    $dataArray = array();

 while ( $qrystmt->fetch() ) { 
      // data array
      $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['CourseName'] = $dbCourseName; 
      $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['Modules'][$dbModuleId]['ModuleName'] = $dbModuleName; 
       // session data
      $_SESSION['idcourse'] = $dbCourseId;
      $_SESSION['namecourse'] = $dbCourseName;

}

 foreach ($dataArray as $courseId => $courseData) {

      $output = ""; 

      $output .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseId .  " - "  . $courseData['CourseName'] . "</p>";

   $moduleHTML = ""; 
   $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modulesDrop" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
   $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
        foreach ($courseData['Modules'] as $moduleId => $moduleData) {        

        $moduleHTML .= "<option value='$moduleId'>" . $moduleId . " - " .   
    $moduleData['ModuleName'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
  } 
        }
        $moduleHTML .= '</select>';

  echo $output;

    }


    ?>

     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="modulesubmit" /></p>      
    </form> 



    <?php

}

 if (isset($_POST['modulesubmit'])) {

 var_dump($_POST['modulesDrop']);

        $sessionquery = "
             SELECT SessionId, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
             FROM Session
             WHERE
             (ModuleId = ?)
             ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
            ";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modulesDrop']);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

 $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

$sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

    $dataArraySession = array();

 while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) { 

 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSessionDate;  
 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime;



}

foreach ($dataArraySession as $sessionId => $sessionData) {

   $sessionHTML = ""; 
   $sessionHTML .= '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
   $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           
   $sessionHTML .= "<option value='$sessionId'>" . $sessionId . " - " . $sessionData['SessionDate']. " - " . $sessionData['SessionTime'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
   $sessionHTML .= '</select>';
        }


 if ($sessionnum > 0) {

 ?>

     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Sessions: <?php echo $sessionHTML; ?><input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="sesionsubmit" /></p>      
    </form>       

<?php

}

else {
 echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Sessions under this Module</p>";
}


}


    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, you have managed to get a module value received after submtting from the module dropdown menu. I am now getting this error `string(7) "CHI2513" Notice: Undefined index: SessionDate in /.../ on line 164 Notice: Undefined index: SessionTime in /.../` The line of code it is pointing to is this line `$dataArraySession[$dbModuleId]['Sessions'][$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSesisonDate['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime; `

Comment: You have 2 assignment operators ie = in this line

Comment: also misspelling $dbSesisonDate instead of $dbSessisonDate

Comment: Oh should it be `$dataArraySession[$dbModuleId]['Sessions'][$dbSessionId] $dbSesisonDate $dbSessionTime; = ['SessionDate']  ['SessionTime']`